# Firebase: data gets removed immediately after pushing to realtime database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

First time poster here!

While I was trying to build a little exercise organizer application with ReactJS and Firebase realtime database I encountered a problem with the Firebase push() method.

I have a couple elements on my page that push data to the database once they are clicked, which looks like this:

```
const planRef = firebase.database().ref("plan");
const currentExName = e.currentTarget.firstChild.textContent;
const exercise = {
     name: currentExName,
     type: e.currentTarget.children[1].textContent,
     user: this.state.user.displayName
};
planRef.push(exercise);
```

Also, if the element is clicked again, then it gets removed from the database like this:

```
planRef.orderByKey().on("value", snapshot => {
            let exercises = snapshot.val();
            for (let ex in exercises) {
                if (exercises[ex].name === currentExName) {
                    planRef.child(ex).set(null);
                }
            }
        });
```

This is working fine as long as I don't try to push something to the database when I just deleted the last bit of data from it. In that case it gets removed right away.

[Data getting removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHb9W.png)

Summary:

1. Write data to the realtime database using `ref.push()`
2. Delete data using `ref.child(child).set(null)` (I tried `remove()` before, same problem)
3. Try to push the same data to the database again which leads to the data getting deleted right after being written to the database

I couldn't find anything about this kind of problem so far so I guess I might have made a mistake somewhere. Let me know if the information provided is not sufficient.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try to do that using `remove()` method instead of `set(null)` ?

Comment: @Curse Yes I did. It‘s what I used originally before using .child(child).set(null).

Answer (score 0):

Removing a child is an asynchronous operation. I guess what is happening here is the removing operation takes more time than the new writing operation. You will need to await for it if you want to write again on the same key.

```
planRef.child(ex).set(null).then(() => {
   planRef.child(ex).push(new);
});
```

Or using async/await:

```
await planRef.child(ex).set(null);
planRef.child(ex).push(new);
```

Let me know if it worked.